# Displaying a 2D Dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays

Sorry if this is a bit of a silly question.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int columns, rows;
  char **map;

  cin>>columns;
  cin>>rows;

  /*creats array of pointers rows tall*/
  map = new char*[rows];

  /*creats array of chars columns tall*/
  for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    map[i] = new char[columns];

  //populate map with input
  map[0][0] = cin.get();
  for(int j=0; j<rows; j++)
    for(int i=0; i<columns; i++)
    {
      if (cin.peek() == '\n')
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
      else
        map[j][i] = cin.get();
    }


  //DISPLAY
  cout<<endl;
  for(int j=0; j<rows; j++)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<columns; i++)
    {
      cout<<map[j][i];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The user will input something like:

```
7 4
#######
#S#   #
#   #E#
#######
```

and I would like to output it.  However mine comes out like:

```
#######
#S#    
##   #
E#####
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Strange part of your code is this line `map[0][0] = cin.get();`. Why do you populate `map[0][0]` once only to populate it again a couple of lines later? I would delete that line for starters.

Comment: If you populate map[0][0] with cin.get() then why do you overwrite it in the for loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for loop:

```
  //populate map with input

  for(int j=0; j<rows; j++)
  {
    cin.get();
    for(int i=0; i<columns; i++)
    {
      if (cin.peek() == '\n')
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
      else
        map[j][i] = cin.get();
    }
  }
```

And add the new line to output:

```
  //DISPLAY
  cout<<endl;
  for(int j=0; j<rows; j++)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<columns; i++)
    {
      cout<<map[j][i];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
```

Always make sure you get the trailing enter out of the input stream before reading it again.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things

- First you don't need `map[0][0] = cin.get();` before the loop since you are going to get `map[0][0]` during the loop
- Second if there is a new line the loop skips it but also does not fill the matrix for that position.
  You should have something like this instead:

> ```
> for(int j=0; j<rows; j++)
>     for(int i=0; i<columns; i++)
>     {
>       while (cin.peek() == '\n')
>         cin.ignore(256, '\n');
>       map[j][i] = cin.get();
>     }
> ```

simply skip(ignore) while there is '\n' character.

- Third, though not related to your question. You should always free dynamicaly allocated memory when finished (in case you have forgotten)

  `delete [] map[i];`
  `delete [] map;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some newlines in your output

```
  for(int j=0; j<rows; j++)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<columns; i++)
    {
      cout<<map[j][i];
    }
    cout << '\n';
  }
```